# how to add to pkg-config search paths on mac?

Tags: macos, pkg-config

I'm trying to add a directory to the pkg-config search paths, but I cannot figure out how to do it on mac.  According to all the discussion I can find online, it looks like it should be according to the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, that variable doesn't seem to exist.

For example:

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

gives a blank response.

Also, I have tried doing this:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/my/path:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

And it does not change the results of `$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`.

How are the pkg-config search paths handled on macOS?

Comment: Huh? You set it with `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/you/want` and view it with `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

Comment: Yes as noted in my answer this does in fact work.  I don't know why it show up blank on echo.

Comment: Because you used `&` instead of `$`

Comment: no this is just a typo in the post.  I will change it now.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is the correct path.  It just does not echo to the console for some reason.